# Custom Scroller

Tags: jquery, css

I need to customize the Browser scrolls (Horz and vert) as per my requirements. and about the customization of div scrollers i know how to do that but i want to customize the main Browser scroller.

I need to minimize it in width so that it can take less width as compare to its default on Win 18pxls.

Shabir Gilkar

Answer (score 0):

You can't customize the main browser scroll bars as they are Operating System and Browser dependent.

A solution that usually works is to wrap the whole content in an absolute positioned DIV with 100% height and width and customize the scrollbars of that DIV.

Comment: Ok, That means we can't customize the browser scrolls... But when we customize the scrolls of the div... i thing i need to hid the scroll of body container...

Comment: If you absolute position the wrapper div and make it fixed there won't be any scrollbars in the browser. Here is an example using jScrollPane - http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/fullBodyScroll.html